# Do most pcs use buffered or unbuffered ram?

Tags: memory

Do most pcs use buffered or unbuffered ram ? I am buying new ram for a really old dell optiplex and I don't know which one to choose

Comment: You should first identify what type of memory you are currently using.  Knowing what most PCs use won't help you guarantee compataiblity with your hardware.  Please provide the necessary information, about your hardware, in order to answer your question.

Comment: You are asking a wrong question. It doesn't matter what's most popular, you could be in the minority.

Comment: @gronostaj I have worked with many PC's, some new some old. The RAM sticks are interchangeable.

Comment: By following that logic, there are two kinds of RAM: one that everyone uses and one that no-one uses. Why the other kind exists and is available for sale is a mystery.

Comment: @gronostaj For servers

Comment: The RAM sticks are interchangeable? So I can interchange DDR, DDR2, DDR3, DDR4, Rambus, EDO, ECC, etc.? How about PC100, PC133, PC3200, PC2-6400, PC3-10600, etc.? It’s a pretty clear answer if you use buffered or unbuffered memory on a desktop, that’s a given, but you do need to match the memory to your system requirements. They are not “interchangeable.”

Comment: @F.Ahmed - ECC and non-ECC modules are not interchangable.

Comment: @Appleoddity Correction:All of the PCs I work with have ddr2 ram. Whether they are buffered or not, I don't know.

Comment: I have at least DDR, DDR2, DDR3, SDRAM, EDO :) and SPI RAM machines at home. well, one that uses SPI is computer but not PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbuffered is for most pc's, buffered is for servers.

Since Optiplex's are not servers then you need unbuffered ram.